# Where is the TopLayoutGuide in my Nib file?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Within my nib file, I've got a UIImageView that I'd like to align to my topLayoutGuide - but I can't seem to find a reference to the topLayoutGuide in the nib file. I'm not using storyboards...

Where is this thing? I'd rather not have to do this adjustment in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you only get top and bottom layout guides if the view belongs to a view controller that's also in the nib.  Set File's Owner to a `UIViewController` is not sufficient.